# IPv6 ranges and Behrouz Forouzan Data Communications and Network book

Tags: ipv6, ip-address

I have been teaching from 2007 edition (4th ed) of the book "Data Communications and Network" (McGraw Hill, Behrouz Forouzan) for a few semesters and I did not notice that the tables on IPv6 ranges might be wrong.

Now that I have obtained a 2013 version of the book (5th ed), I see the ranges are totally different (especially the Unicast range). Notice that 001 prefix was mentioned to be reserved in 2007 edition (and 2 other ranges were mentioned for ISP unicast 010 and Geographical unicast ranges 100).

**2007 Edition**
[image: 1st half of the table]
[image: 1st half of the table]

**2013 Edition**
[image: Summary of usable ranges]

Could someone tell me whether this is a horrible mistake in a widely used textbook or something has changed in between the editions?

How do you suggest me to describe the discrepancy to the students?

Comment: RFCs are being added all the time. For instance, [RFC 5156, Special-Use IPv6 Addresses](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5156) is from April, 2008, and IANA's [Internet Protocol Version 6 Address Space](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-address-space/ipv6-address-space.xhtml) was last updated on 10/22/2015.

Comment: Thank you. But do they change so dramatically? What about unicast IP addresses allocated before 2008?

Comment: From [RFC 3578, IPv6 Global Unicast Address Format](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3587), August, 2003: "_RFC 2374 (July 1998) was the definition of addresses for Format Prefix 001 (2000::/3) which is formally made historic by this document. Even though currently only 2000::/3 is being delegated by the IANA, implementations should not make any assumptions about 2000::/3 being special. In the future, the IANA might be directed to delegate currently unassigned portions of the IPv6 address space for the purpose of Global Unicast as well._" You just need to search the RFCs and IANA for reality.